# Return an interpretation by reference

Tags: c++

I have an array of bytes Data[], I access the unstructured items in it by this function:

```
    inline HItem* AtP(const uint32_t &PosB) {
        return reinterpret_cast<HItem*>(Data + PosB);
    }
```

Where I pass the beginning offset of HItem to the function (they are variable size), this works fine.

I tried this however:

```
    inline HItem& At(const uint32_t &PosB) {
        return *reinterpret_cast<HItem*>(Data + PosB);
    }
```

But I got a stack corruption error since the object it returns is not the one physically located in the memory address I specified but rather something else (not sure if random).

What is wrong with the second function? Is it even possible?

Comment: I'll bet the reality is that "this works fine" is a misunderstanding. If it did, then what is returned from AtP would permit, say, HItem & d( *hi), but I'll bet that's not going to be correct. The notion of using reinterpret_cast for something as simple as an array baffles me, so, tell me why that's required..because 99.9999% of the time, it's not.

Comment: These two versions are both equivalent in functionality if `PosB` is not out of bounds, so if you see a problem one way it means there is actually a problem in both cases, it is just so happening that you don't see anything the first time. You will need to debug your program.

Comment: Maybe add in a check that `PosB < dimension_of_Data`

Comment: I rechecked everything along the way, the error pops up no matter what PosB is. When PosB is 0 then the returned pointer should be pointing to the same address as Data is which in case of the first snippet is true. In the second snippet, when I check the address of the appointed variable, this is false.

Comment: I think the second function is returning a copy of the HItem instead, its internal values are correct but its address isn't